# Сериализация в XML. XmlSerializer с#

Tags: сериализация

Добрый день, дано такое задание :

> Дан файл, в первых трех столбцах записаны фамилия, имя и отчество, а в
>   четвёртом — адрес электронной почты. Написать программу для
>   преобразования файла в формат XML

мой код :

```
public class Person
    {



        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string SName { get; set; }
        public string OName { get; set; }
        public string Mail { get; set; }

        public Person()

        { }



        public Person(string name, string sname, string oname, string mail)
        {

            Name = name;
            SName = sname;
            OName = oname;
            Mail = mail;


        }

    }


    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            string filename = @"C:\test\1.txt";



            string line;

            Person person;
            person = new Person();
      //     Person[] people = new Person[] { person };

            XmlSerializer formatter = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Person));

            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@filename);

while (!sr.EndOfStream)
{
   line = sr.ReadLine();
   string[] ss = line.Split(';');
   Console.WriteLine(ss[0]);
   Console.WriteLine(ss[1]);
   Console.WriteLine(ss[2]);
   Console.WriteLine(ss[3]);
   Console.WriteLine("------------");
   person.Name = ss[0];
   person.SName = ss[1];
   person.OName = ss[2];
   person.Mail = ss[3];

   using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"C:\test\people1.xml", FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
   {
       formatter.Serialize(fs, person);
   }

}      
                sr.Close();
```

тк считываю я данные из файла, то получается, что он сериализует только последную строку, как мне записать все строки ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Делайте вот как.

Для начала, заведите класс, который будет содержать все экземпляры `Person`:

```
public class PersonList
{
    public List<Person> Persons { get; set; }
}
```

Заведите экземпляр в программе:

```
var list = new List<Person>();
```

Считайте данные в него:

```
using (var sr = new StreamReader(filename))
{
    while (!sr.EndOfStream)
    {
        string line = sr.ReadLine();
        string[] ss = line.Split(';');
        var person = new Person(ss[0], ss[1], ss[2], ss[3]);
        list.Add(person);
    }
}
```

И запишите целый объект:

```
var pl = new PersonList() { Persons = list };
var seri = new XmlSerializer(typeof(PersonList));
using (var file = File.Create(@"C:\test\people1.xml"))
    seri.Serialize(file, pl);
```

---

Дополнение: В принципе, вы можете обойтись даже без `PersonList`:

```
var seri = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Person>));
using (var file = File.Create(@"C:\test\people1.xml"))
    seri.Serialize(file, list);
```

(Корневым элементом будет `ArrayOfPerson`.)

Comment: спасибо за ответ, сделал с помощью коллекции , намного проще

Comment: @Lolidze: Пожалуйста!

Comment: сделал по вашему примеру, намного красивее и то, что надо, еще раз спасибо

Comment: @Lolidze: Дополнил ответ ещё одним вариантом.

Answer (score 1):

Вы переписываете файл people1.xml на каждой итерации цикла while. Вам нужен один stream для файла-результата на протяжении всего чтения.

```
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"C:\test\people1.xml", FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
{
  while (!sr.EndOfStream)
  {
   line = sr.ReadLine();
   string[] ss = line.Split(';');
   Console.WriteLine(ss[0]);
   Console.WriteLine(ss[1]);
   Console.WriteLine(ss[2]);
   Console.WriteLine(ss[3]);
   Console.WriteLine("------------");
   person.Name = ss[0];
   person.SName = ss[1];
   person.OName = ss[2];
   person.Mail = ss[3];

   formatter.Serialize(fs, person);
  }
}
```

Comment: я так тоже пытался, но так отображается не верно, тобишь, при открытии одна голая первая строка с пробелами. Нужно как-то сделать ArrayOfPerson, ибо щас выходит, что для каждой строки пишется свой  Person xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" , а должно быть ,по идее, все под одним